How to check if GeoPolygon is specified in counterclockwise order?
In Azure.Core.GeoJson there is a GeoPolygon class. How can one check in C# if the points in that GeoPolygon are specified in counterclockwise order?
This matters with Cosmos DB because the documentation states: "Points within a Polygon must be specified in counter-clockwise order. A Polygon specified in clockwise order represents the inverse of the region within it."
